# Rearrange an algebraic expression so that each variable appears only once

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Mathematica gave me a solution to an equation in this form:

`ans1 = (b c)/(a - a c + b c)`

$\text{ans1} = \frac{b c}{a - a c + b c}$

From solving the same equation by hand, I know of an alternative form in which each variable appears only once:

`ans2 = 1/(1 + (1/c - 1) a/b)`

$ \text{ans2} = \frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{1}{c}-1\right)\frac{a }{b}} $

Running `Simplify[ans2]` gives `ans1`. Is there a systematic way to obtain `ans2` from `ans1`?

In numerical analysis, expressions like `ans2` are called "single use expressions". They also show up in [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic#Dependency_proble).

I'm particularly interested in a method that could work for other expressions besides the given example, although I'm not sure it's possible to isolate each variable in general, e.g. `a/(a+b)`.

Edit: @bbgodfrey has pointed out that `a/(a+b)` can be transformed into a single-use expression.

Edit: in numerical analysis, these are called "single use expressions".

> It is known that this problem is easy to solve when we have a Single Use Expression, i.e., an expression in which each variable $x_i$ occurs only once.

https://doi.org/10.1109/NAFIPS.2011.5752032

> In a linear expression $f = a_0 + a_1 \cdot \Delta x_1 + \ldots + a_n \cdot \Delta x_n$, each variable $\Delta x i \in [-\Delta_i , \Delta_i ]$ occurs only once. It is known that for such *single-use expressions* (SUE), straightforward interval computations leads to the exact range;

https://doi.org/10.1007/11558958_9

> In general, it can be shown that the exact range of values can be achieved, if each variable appears only once and if $f$ is continuous inside the box. However, not every function can be rewritten this way.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic

Comment: The goal is in general not achievable, so one would have to clearly narrow down the cases to which the simplification will be applied. One could come up with something that works for this case, but then it may not work for others. There are some methods that can achieve special forms not obtainable by `Simplify`. For example, `HornerForm`. But this particular goal is not a standard normal form, so you'd have to fiddle with replacement rules that break easily.

Comment: By the way, these are called "single use expressions" in numerical analysis.

Comment: For example, interval arithmetic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic

Comment: Dear @bariumbitmap - may I suggest that you edit your question rather than post comments if you have additional information?

Comment: @Verbeia Thanks, I've done so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following approach transforms `ans1` to `ans2` and points the way to more general approaches.

As noted in the Question, `Simplify` returns `ans1` unchanged.  Introducing a `ComplexityFunction` that defines fewer symbols as less complex helps some.

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, _Symbol, Infinity]
Simplify[ans1, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
(* (b*c)/(-(a*(-1 + c)) + b*c) *)
```

Noting that `Simplify` does not try such substitutions as `(c-1)/c -> 1-1/c`, we introduce `TransformationFunctions`

```
tf1[e_] := e /. (z_ + zz_)/z_ :> 1 + zz/z
tf2[e_] := e /. z_/(z_ + zz_) :> 1/(1 + zz/z)
Simplify[ans1, ComplexityFunction -> cf, 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1, tf2}]
(* (1 - (a*(1 - c^(-1)))/b)^(-1) *)
```

which is `ans2`, as desired.

This approach also works for `a/(a+b)`, mentioned at the end of the Question.

```
Simplify[a/(a + b), ComplexityFunction -> cf, 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1, tf2}]
(* (1 + b/a)^(-1) *)
```

It is not difficult to imagine other expressions for which the specific `TransformationFunctions` used here are not sufficient.  However, it seems likely that introducing additional `TransformationFunctions` might well transform a wide range of expressions.